# Is the inverse of a bijective monotone function also monotone?

Tags: real-analysis, functions, inverse

**If $f$ is bijective and monotonic function is $f^{-1}$ monotonic?**

Here is my attempt at solving the question but I'm unsure wether it's the right way to proceed or not.

Mathematical translation of $f$ is bijective and monotonic:

$\forall x,  f(x)\le f(x+1)$ or  $f(x)\ge f(x+1)$

We have $f^{-1}(x)=x$ therefore and $x\le x+1$ therefore $f^{-1}$ is monotonic.

Comment: Bijective function $\ne$ identity function

Comment: What are the domain and codomain of $f$? Are we talking about a linear ordered set or just some partially ordered set?

Comment: Isn't $f^{-1}(x)=x$?

Comment: @Mathphilo No, it is not. Consider function $f(x)=x+1$ which is a monotonic bijection $\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$

Answer (score 1):

Hint #1:  Let $f: D \rightarrow C$ be a bijective function with domain $D$ and codomain $C$.  Then $f$ is monotonic implies that there exist $x, y \in D$ such that
$$x \leq y \implies f(x) \leq f(y)$$
(if $f$ is monotonic increasing), or
$$x \geq y \implies f(x) \geq f(y)$$
(if $f$ is monotonic decreasing).

Hint #2:  If $f: D \rightarrow C$ is bijective, then $f^{-1}: C \rightarrow D$ is also bijective.

Hint #3:  The compositions
$$f(f^{-1}(x)) = x$$
and
$$f^{-1}(f(x)) = x$$
hold.

Can you take it from here?

Answer (score 0):

Let $U$ and $V$ be subsets of $\mathbb{R}$. Without loss of generality suppose that $f:U\rightarrow V$ is strictly increasing.

Suppose that $f^{-1}$ is not increasing, ie. there are $y_1<y_2$ in $V$ such that $f^{-1}(y_1)\ge f^{-1}(y_2)$. Let $x_1=f^{-1}(y_1)$ and $x_2=f^{-1}(y_2)$. Since $f$ is bijection we have$$f(x_1)=f(f^{-1}(y_1))=y_1<y_2=f(f^{-1}(y_2))=f(x_2)$$
which is contradiction because $x_1\ge x_2$.